# Pass Firebase Record Key into URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angular-routing

I'm adding an item to a Firebase array on page1, this is done when the user clicks the "Complete" button. However, I also want to load the next page using ng-route in which the record is retrieved. I'm wanting unique URLs that can be accessed again by the user, this is why I'm having it directly append it to the URL.

The method in which I'm using at the moment is to have the record added in the first function and retrieve the key at that time in which I bind to the scope with the appropriate url (See Snippet #2). In the second function listed in the ng-click I'm having it perform the route with the appended Key in the url.

With this setup it is adding the record, but not taking me to the correct page, it is defaulting to the main page. I'm wondering if it is because it hasn't resolved the promise in my $add and therefore wasn't able to append it to the url before it ran the second function in the scope.

Any help is greatly appreciated and if you need more of my code just let me know!

```
//Snippet from page1.html (Within appCtrl and form scope)
<button ng-click="form.storeCheck(); appCtrl.pageLoad(form.urlKey)" ng-disabled="checkVerifyForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right">Complete</button>

//Snippet from Page1Controller (form.storeCheck)
this.checkList.$add(this.check).then(function(ref){
  this.urlKey = 'spec/:'+ref.key();

//Snippet from AppController (appCtrl.pageLoad)
this.pageLoad = function(page){
  $location.path('/'+page);

//Snippet from config ng-route
.when('/spec/:urlKey', {
  templateUrl: 'views/spec.html',
  controller: 'SpecController',
  controllerAs: 'spec'
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ng-click="form.storeCheck(); appCtrl.pageLoad(form.urlKey)"
```

In this code, you are saying run  appCtrl.pageLoad() straight after form.storeCheck() which would be fine if this was an offline application with no data involved but in relality, appCtrl.pageLoad should only be called when storeCheck has been resolved which is not what you have implied here.

There are multiple ways to fix this issue and perhaps the easiest way is to do all this in one controller

in your Page1Controller, add $location as a dependency

```
this.checkList.$add(this.check).then(function(ref){
  $location.path('/spec/:'+ref.key());
}
```

Change your html to

```
<button ng-click="form.storeCheck();"
```

Comment: Thanks! I very well may resolve to using that solution. But first I only wonder what it would take to have it work in this current setup? Is there a way to call both functions in the ngclick in the view but have the first wait until the promise resolves to fire?

Comment: firebase is resolved asynchronously which means it will be resolved after all synchronous code is complete even if the synchronous code takes longer to complete than the asynchronous code.  What this means is that no matter what appCtrl.pageLoad(form.urlKey) will run before firebase is resolved.  If you want to run them in different controllers then you can use a broadcast.  But I suggest either putting the code in a service or putting it in the same controller.